# Javascript removeEventListener doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, lightbox, event-listener

So for a website I have a feature where If you click an image it shows it in a lightbox then on the second click it tracks the mouse movement to move the image. That works fine the problem is on the third click I want to toggle the mouse tracking on and off.

I've posted a simplified version of the code with a button instead of an image

```html
<body>

<div id="myDIV"></p>
  <button style="padding: 30px;" id="myBtn">Try it</button>
</div>



<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
document.addEventListener('click', buttonClick);
let scrollon =false;

function buttonClick(event) {
      var elem = event.target,
        elemID = elem.getAttribute('id'),
        myBtn = document.getElementById('myBtn');
        

         if (elemID == 'myBtn' && !scrollon){
            event.preventDefault();
            scrollon=true;
             mine();
             console.log('triggered')

         }else

         if (elemID == 'myBtn' && scrollon){
            event.preventDefault();
             scrollon=false;
             mine();
             console.log('untriggered')
         }         

}
function mine(){
    if (scrollon == false){
        myBtn.removeEventListener('mousemove',scroll);
        return;
    }
    myBtn.addEventListener('mousemove',scroll);
    
    function scroll(e){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Math.random(); //keeps going
            //do something
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: why remove event if you can keep some bool flag variable which will determine if you can scroll or not?

Comment: The thing is neither method seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very good alternative code which works perfectly fine and is used very often.
So I only changed the mine() function.

```
function mine() {
  if (scrollon == false) {
    myBtn.onmousemove = null;
  } else {
    myBtn.onmousemove = function (e) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Math.random(); //keeps going
      //do something
    };
  }
}
```

Hope I could help!

Comment: Excellent this works perfectly, I'm not exactly sure how.

I suppose I can change the mouse move to a drag function for mobile use too.